# Solve simultaneous linear equations with three unknown variables

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Solve the following:

$3x−2y+z=7$

$x+y+z=2$

$3x−2y−z=3$

I know I have to find one of the variables by elimination or substitution, which will lead to two equations and two unknown variables, which I can then go on to solve.

However, I'm totally lost on this, and keep getting the wrong answer.

Comment: Well, what steps are you specifically taking? We can't really address any potential misconceptions you have unless you tell us those - us going through the steps for solving this for you won't be nearly as helpful for you.

Comment: I was failing to eliminate the z, to get x and y. Then once I had x and y, I could go back and plug those in to find z. It's clear now thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subtract the second equation from the first equation to get $2x-3y=5$.

Add the first equation and the third equation to get $6x-4y=10$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Thank you! Very clear and concise.

Answer (score 2):

From the first and the third equations we obtain $z=2$ and $x+y=0$, which gives $$(1,-1,2)$$